# Sum the results I already have on screen

Tags: python

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000

Solution :

```
def multi(n):

  if n <= 1 :
    return 0
  elif n%3 == 0 or n%5 == 0:
    s = n
    print s
    return multi (n-1)
  else:
    return multi (n-1)

a = input("Enter value")
multi(a-1)
```

Though I am able to print all the numbers below 1000 that are divisible by 3 and 5, I am not able to add them. I don't want the solution, all I need is a hint. I tried adding it but what I received was the "int and Nonetype can't be added" error.

Comment: recursion is really not the way to go with this

Comment: Can you show your solution where you did add?

Comment: use iteration, `yield` the numbers to add, and catch the yield inside a `sum`..

Comment: Ah, the classic FizzBuzz.

Comment: That "Question 1" makes it sound like this is for a test or exam. Is it?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Smells to me like Project Euler.

Comment: I tried using sum(multi(a-1)) in last line. It showed "int" object is not iterable .

Comment: Yes, First problem of Project Euler!

Comment: try adding instead of printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually do the addition at some point. The correct code is:

```
def multi(n):
  if n <= 1 :
    return 0
  elif n%3 == 0 or n%5 == 0:
    return n + multi (n-1)
  else:
    return multi (n-1)

a = input("Enter value")
multi(a-1)
```

Comment: Tried this , its not giving any result.

Comment: @ArjitKapoor Just tried it, it works, make sure your indentation is legal and try it again. Copy paste job.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably a filtering generator expression:

```
def multi(n):
    return sum(item for item in range(n) if not (item%3 and item%5))
```

Keep in mind that, as the very first Project Euler problem, the difficulty on subsequent problems goes nowhere but up.

Comment: Any suggestion for noob on How to tackle problem and on solving it?

Comment: @ArjitKapoor You can actually figure this out without writing a line of code. Honing that skill will be critical for later Project Euler problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
fives = [x for x in range(0,1000,5)]
threes= [x for x in range(0,1000,3)] 

print( sum(list(set(fives) | set(threes))))
```

get the list of all fives and threes union and sum it up.